# Not able to write loop expression in withcolumn in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

i have dataframe where DealKeys has data like as
[{"Charge_Type": "DET", "Country": "VN", "Tariff_Loc": "VNSGN"}]

expected out put could be
[{"keyname": "Charge_Type", "value": "DET", "description": "..."}, {"keyname": "Country", "value": "VN", "description": "..."}, {"keyname": "Tariff_Loc", "value": "VNSGN", "description": "..."}]

when i create dataframe got bellow error
df = df2.withColumn('new_column',({'keyname' : i, 'value' : dictionary[i],'description' : "..."} for i in col("Dealkeys")))

Errro: Column is not iterable

DF2 schema:

```
root
 |-- Charge_No: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DealKeys: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- Charge_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Tariff_Loc: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot iterate through a dataframe column in Pyspark, hence the error occured.

To get the expected output, you need to follow the approach specified below.

- Create `new_column` column with value as an empty string beforehand so that we can update its value as we iterate through each row.
- Since a column cannot be iterated, we can use `collect()` method to get `DealKeys` values so that we can insert them into the corresponding new_column value.
- Using `df.collect()` returns a list of rows (rows can be iterated through). As per schema, DealKeys is also of type `Row`. Using `dealkey_row` (DealKeys column values as a row) with `asDict()`, perform list comprehension to create the list of dictionaries that will be inserted into corresponding `Charge_No` value.

```
# df is the initial dataframe
df = df.withColumn("new_column", lit(''))

rows = df.collect()
for row in rows:
    key = row[0]    #Charge_No column value (string type)
    dealkey_row = row[2][0]    #DealKeys column value (row type)
    
    lst = [{'keyname' : i, 'value' : dealkey_row[i],'description' : "..."} for i in dealkey_row.asDict()]    #row.asDict() to get dictionary
    
    df = df.withColumn('new_column', when(col('Charge_No') == key, str(lst)).otherwise(col('new_column')))
    
df.show(truncate=False)
```

- Row.asDict() converts a row into a dictionary so that the list comprehension can be easily. Using `withColumn()` along with `when(<condition>,<update_value>)` function in pyspark, insert the output of your list comprehension into the `new_column` column (‘otherwise’ helps to retain the previous value if `Charge_No` value doesn’t match).

The above code produced the following output when I used it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post.It was not in string type for the deal key.Below is the format of dataframe :Charge_No:string
Status:string
DealKeys:array
element:struct
Charge_Type:string
Country:string
Tariff_Loc:string

Comment: Tried another way but not able to add in withcolumn transformation                                                       def get_delakeys(df_lt):
    start=[]
    for index,row in df_lt.toPandas().iterrows():
        for i in ['Charge_Type','Country']:
            final = {"keyanme" : i,"value" : row[i],"description":".."}
            start.append(final)
        #final_val= {"value" : row['Charge_Type']}
    #start.append(final_val)
    return start

Comment: Hey @JayaPrakash, is Charge_No a unique key column in the dataframe? Or are there duplicate values in that column?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the schema of the dataframe. Please confirm if it is correct. If it is not, please edit the question to provide an image of the correct schema.

Comment: I have added schema details and charge_no is the unique key

Comment: @JayaPrakash, I have updated the answer which is done using the same approach as before with necessary changes. I will provide an answer using the get_dealkeys() user defined function also.

Comment: @SaideepArikonthamt thanks for your erfforts. its working fine now..if we use df.collect() may give perfromance issues..

Comment: Great @JayaPrakash, Can you please post the method as an answer so it helps to understand how it is done?

Comment: can you see the new_column datatype is stored as string, but need to store same as dealkeys